# How to scan for 2 ActionCommands

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I start to write a programm, where you can buy tickets.

The problem is that after `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)`,
I have two if clauses, but it will jump over the second one.

```
if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("Einzelkarte")) {
    ersteAbfrage1.setVisible(false);
    ersteAbfrage2.setVisible(false);
    ersteAbfrage3.setVisible(false);
    zweiteAbfrage.setVisible(true);
    Auswahl1.setVisible(true);
    Preise.setVisible(false);
    System.out.println("Test");
    evt.getActionCommand();
    if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("normales")){
        zweiteAbfrage.setVisible(false);
        dritteAbfrage.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }
}
System.out.println("Test1");
```

If I press the Button "Einzelkarte", it will print:

```
 Test
 Test1
```

Is there a way, that it will "scan" a second button in the second if clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on a button than the listener executes. At this moment, you have a single command in the `actionPerformed`- method. For your example you need something like a radio button or checkbox for the other condition.